# Location of Microsoft access database for windows form when creating setup file using installshield

Tags: c#, winforms, database-connection, connection-string

I have developed windows form which uses Microsoft Access Database.

During development i have put database file in root folder with in project.

When i run application through visual studio, it run fine  but when i create installation file and install it in my system i get following error.

When i create the installation file my database location is

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb
```

How can i solve this?

**Error**

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Purchase_Management.Form1..ctor() in c:\Users\Amrit\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Purchase Management\Purchase Management\Purchase Management System.cs:line 19
   at Purchase_Management.Main_Window.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Amrit\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Purchase Management\Purchase Management\Main Window.cs:line 27
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Purchase Management
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Amrit%20Creations/aDesigns/Purchase%20Management/obj/Release/Purchase%20Management.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18037 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18022 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked if the database exists in the installation location ?

Comment: i checked the location after installation and it does exists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the error is not about the `connectionString` or something about your database, I say, because if that error is about the `database path` it should be like this image

[image]

If that error is like that image. Try place your database and application in the same folder.

Okay I found out, you clearly place the database in the wrong place.. try to move that database in the `bin` folder

Comment: yes same error..My first window opens fine but when i try to open second window which has combo box on it which populates items from database. So i think it has no idea where to fetch data from and throws above error..but then i debug application from visual studio it runs fine..

Comment: so do i have to change the connection string in the app.config or just move database to \Resources\App_Data\Database.accdb

Comment: If the database and your application is in the same folder. the `connectionString` should be like this `Provider=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|/database.accdb`

Comment: thats quite strange.. `:D`

Comment: its something to do with database link but i don't know where i am wrong. All the other windows which doesnot need database works fine..

Comment: try check your codes.. try to clear your codes and test and test `:D`

Comment: i checked my code, all works if i debug application using visual studio. Problem happens when i create installtion file and install it on the system..

Comment: so, where did you place your database? try to rebuild your setup project in times you have changes in your main project.

Comment: if u like to check i can send you the entire solution